# Click on :before or :after pseudo element icons to make gallery scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, pseudo-element

I'm dealing with a Wordpress site, so I have limited access to what I can add or not and where. I had to use :before and :after pseudo elements to add two arrow icons. these icons are supposed to achieve some scrolling in the div element they are part of when they are clicked.

```
<div class="thumbs-gallery">
  ::before
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  ::after
 </div>
```

The way this is set up, you can only see 2 thumbs as "thumbs-gallery" has a fixed height and an overflow set to auto.

```
.thumbs-gallery {
    width: 135px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -601px;
    height: 506px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.thumbs-gallery::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url('...') no-repeat;
    background-size: 37px 25px;
    width: 38px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 830px;
    top: -630px;
}

.thumbs-gallery::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url('...') no-repeat;
    background-size: 37px 25px;
    width: 38px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 830px;
    top: -50px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

How can I target the before and after pseudo elements with JQuery and have it scroll the content inside of "thumbs-gallery" up and down?

Comment: You can't: pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM and therefore cannot be selected by JS (and therefore jQuery). You will need to create DOM elements for the previous and next buttons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)